# What happens if I remove the executive of a program while it is running?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am using linux. What happens if I remove an executive file that is running (I tried and the program is still running)?  What if I remove the linked object files? Does it make a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove a file in Linux. You can only remove directory entries pointing to the file. The file itself will eventually be removed by the Operating System when there are no more references to the file: no more directory entries pointing to the file, no more open file handles, no more memory mapped regions and so on.

As long as the program is running, there is still a reference to the file, so the file simply won't get removed.

Deleting a library that has already been loaded is the same. The only problems can arise when you delete a library that will only be opened later in the runtime of the program.